# Trying to solve ODE system in MATLAB yields the following error: "Undefined function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'cell'"

Tags: matlab, simulink, ode, function-handle, undefined-function

I'm having a bit of difficulties when I try to solve an ODE system of two equations in MATLAB.

The code I am using is the following:

```
x0=-1;              %Initial condition for variable x
y0=-10;             %Initial condition for variable y
dx=@(t,x,y) y+2.*t; %First ODE
dy=@(t,y) y;        %Second ODE
f={dx;dy};          %Array that contains the first and second ODE's

[t,g]=ode15s(f,[0 1],[x0 y0]);  %Call for ode15s solver
```

When I execute this code, i get the following error:

> Undefined function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

I don't want to create a function of the style

```
function f=myodes(t,x,y)
etc etc
end
```

Because this code is intended to be nested in a function code, which is then going to be inserted in a MATLAB Function block in Simulink, which needs to use, as inputs, the outputs of other blocks in the Simulink file.

I cannot do it directly on Simulink because that code is actually a practice for a larger set of equations that I need to solve, where the independent variable is not time but distance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And what makes you think you cannot use a function of the form you propose? Take a look at the docs on [local functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html).

Comment: Note that Simulink solves the differential equations that the system represents at each time step, so there's no need to (and you shouldn't) call `ode15s` and try to solve the differential equations within the MATLAB Function block.

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis: I took a look at the Nested functions section of the MATLAB help but I believed that this could be done without the need of Nested functions and with less code lines. And your answer proves my point.

Comment: @am304: I cannot let Simulink sole my differential equations because my independent variable is not time (as is the ind. variable taken by Simulink); in my code, time controls the inputs to the block but not the operations executed inside it. I'm just curious if this is going to work in the Simulink environment the way I intend to. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @elporsche But `ode15s` solve differential equations with respect to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the substitution

```
z ≣ [x; y]
```

such that

```
dz ≣ [dx; dy]
```

You'd implement this as

```
x0 = -1;    %// Initial condition for variable x
y0 = -10;   %// Initial condition for variable y

%// The ODEs. Note that z ≣ [x; y]
f = @(t,z) [
    z(2)        %// First ODE
    z(2)+2*t];  %// Second ODE

%// Call for ode15s solver
[t,g] = ode15s(f, [0 1], [x0 y0])
```

Only thing left to do is properly demux your outputs.